# Basic about Intents - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

What are the contents of a passive data structure (of a intent) ?
 Why they are considered as late run time binding. ?

i know this late run time question is already on this forum but i donot like the answer much ...
it says "Because it is not a compile-time binding between components ".Can someone please explain in a bit detail?

It would be great if someone answer it with an example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the question is allready on here (it's a Q&A site btw, not a forum :) ), wouldn't that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html Better documentation

Comment: sorry for that its a site. i asked two questions : first question is not available on the site  , however second one is there but not well answered.